# How to store object in sqlite database?

Tags: android

Is it possible to store user defined objects in a SQLite database from Android? For example: I am creating one class and I want to store that class object in the database.  Is it possible? If it is, how to proceed? On the Blackberry platform, I am able to store objects directly in persistent objects.  Is it possible to do this with SQLite and Android?

Answer (score 24):

You'll need to be able to serialize your object into a byte stream and then recreate your object from a byte stream.

Then, just store that byte stream in your db.

EDIT:
Read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-07-2000/jw-0714-flatten.html) to learn about serialization in Java. It caters to the subject in a much better way than I would be able to by just giving some code snippets.

Comment: can u pls provide me some code snippet to do serialization of object.

Comment: I edited the answer and give a link to an article which teaches you how to do object serialization.

Comment: link leads to Oracle Java start page that has no information about serialization

Comment: Link rot. A little more detail would've been better!

Comment: I was under the impression, that SQLite actually serves the purpose of quickly storing objects in a DB. I've used it for exactly that purpose in other applications. Is it really so, that we can't use SQLite like you'd use it in non-Android apps? Why use SQLite at all on Andorid then, if you have to do SQL Statements anyway? I don't get it. Why did they include SQLite then?

Comment: The link appears to be dead and no longer go anywhere. Says page not found when visited for me in 2023.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of storing them in SQLite why not store them in [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android/), which is specifically designed for storing objects. A simple [tutorial](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-database-for-objects-db4o-in.html) for sotring objects using db4o.

Comment: DB4O is great in principle. It's super easy to use. BUT unfortunately it has many bugs and development/maintenance seems to have completely stopped. Very sad situation.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code to convert your object to byte array and store it in your database as "BLOB"

```
public byte[] makebyte(Dataobject modeldata) {
            try {

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                oos.writeObject(modeldata);
                byte[] employeeAsBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(employeeAsBytes);
                return employeeAsBytes;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Use this code to convert your byte array to your object again

```
public Dataobject read(byte[] data) {
    try {


        ByteArrayInputStream baip = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(baip);
        Dataobject dataobj = (Dataobject ) ois.readObject();
        return dataobj ;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```